# Non-shared, per user, Wordpress (PHP) installation

Tags: apache-2.2, php, virtualhost, wordpress

What's the recommended method of doing Apache based PHP virtual hosting installations where each site would have one and just one user allocated for it?

- Read and execute for one user per site only (not `www-data` or all users)
- `/srv/www` installation folder (not `/home`, the user does not have a shell)
- Write access limited to one folder

As I believe this would add some security against the cases where one site get compromised on a shared host.

I'd be grateful for pointers to tools, tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not `/home`, just because the user doesn't have a shell?  The whole process is quite straightforward, you just create the user-per-site, make the permissions appropriately, and then, most importantly, run PHP as the user (with suPHP or php-fpm).  Sudo really never comes into it.

Comment: Thanks. I clarified the title - I mean sudo as "switch user" not sudo the command